# Kettle Connections Dropping on Transformation/Job Reload

Tags: etl, kettle

I have a job with multiple transformations stored in a MySQL repository. The transformations have steps that connect to different databases, such as table input and combination lookup/update.

When I reload the the job and try to execute it, the connections have all dropped from the transformations. I have to go back and edit the transformations to point to the correct database.

This doesn't happen all the time. Most of the time, I notice it after I have been disconnected from the repository by leaving it on over night and have to reconnect.

Is this a known bug or user error on my part?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure no one and nothing else is able to mess with the tables in your repository? Do you see your connections in the repository explorer? Are you sure it's saving your jobs/transforms properly? And why do you get disconnected if you leave it on overnight?

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? 
I have tested the last version and the problem still continues.
In the past the problem was solved saving the connections first and reopen the transformation before doing additional actions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Pentaho Wiki - to use MySQL as repo there are various things which must be configured in MySQL to make it work reliably - specifically using innodb and various other db tweaks.

I have seen this before though, it's specific to mysql in my experience. Check the above first though.  In my experience it was rare, but did happen from time to time.

Obviously you will get disconnected overnight because of the mysql timeout.  There are settings to control that, and the same issue causes problems in the BI server too, which is why everyone uses c3po instead.. However I wouldn't worry about that I don't believe it's related to the connections being lost issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the connections being removed from the transformation definition.

This happens also with other connection types. I don't know really the cause but I have found a solution inspired on this: http://bit.ly/1MrGkgc

Just have to go to have to right click on the connection in Spoon, and select "Share".

Then the connection is not removed the next time the transformation is loaded.